# Calling @Asynchronous metod from library on Wildfly Linux

Tags: linux, asynchronous, ejb, wildfly-8

I've encounter some problem while applying a small library to send email using wildfly email resource
Idea with library is to provide singleton providing asynchronous method to send emails.
 in short service looks like

```
@Singleton
public class MailService {

    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MailService.class.getName());

    @Inject
    private Session session;

    @Asynchronous
    public void sendEmail(final EmailModel email) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            if (email.normalRecipientsListIsEmpty()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("need destination address.");
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email.getNormalRecipients()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(email.getCCRecipients()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(email.getBCCRecipients()));

            message.setSubject(email.getSubject());

            message.setContent(email.getContent(), MIME_TYPE);
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to sen email.", e);
        }

    }

}
```

Injected session is produced in project via `@Produces` annotation in `Stateless` service field.
While on windows everything works fine, however if deployed on wildfly running on linux, there is an timeout exception with message like "could not obtain a lock on method within 5000milis"
When i moved whole code to project, with no changes, everything started to work perfectly.

My question is, why is this happening? Is there a difference in implementation somewhere or in configuration? How can i fix that and move code back to library where it can be reused in other projects?

Comment: What do you mean by project here?

Comment: Other web applications of course. If that could be any clue, all projects we do are a modular maven projects packaged to ear + web module packaged to war which contains all modules.

Comment: All singletons' methods have Lock.Write type by default. Could you check and compare default-access-timeout for singletons in both configuration? Have you checked also whether on Linux mail server is up and running (don't know how exactly you send those mails)? I would recommend also adding some logs in order to determine where this method actually hangs.